# Data-INTO and XML-Into

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

what is the exact difference between XML-INTO and DATA-INTO. I know what XML-INTO is but not much idea on what DATA-INTO is. Can anyone please help me understand this.

Comment: This question is really beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  There are a good handful of articles out there the explain what DATA-INTO is.  Scott Klement has a pretty decent article for COMMON here: https://www.common.org/scotts-iland-blog/parsing-json-data-into/.  He also lists a couple other articles by Jon Paris and Susan Gantner for more followup.  If you dig into those and come back with a more specific technical question, that would be a good time to post it here.

Comment: THanks @Player1st  . I went through Scott's artcle and got an idea of what Data-Into Can do. Looks like he is using the system parser (YAJLINTO) which is used for Parsing Json. I also checked Susan/Jon article where they have written a custom parser.. My question is, like we have YAJLINTO for JSON data, do we not have other system parsers for other type of data(Like CSV) so that we do not have to write a Parser on our Own.. (Susan did give a code sample to write a custom CSV parser).. Thanks for Your time

Comment: YAJLINTO isn't a system parser.  YAJL is an open source library to parse JSON that Scott ported over to the IBM i.  He then wrote a wrapper around it to make it usable with DATA-INTO.  That is the whole point of DATA-INTO.  It allows any developer to write a wrapper for a particular format and use it with DATA-INTO in order to parse any format out there.  With a bit of work from the community, open source parsers could available from the community to handle the various file formats out there.